# How to create website link with an alternate custom port?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lamp

I would want my website subdomain a.site.com to be accessible via alternate port, lets say a.site.com:8866

How can i enable this? a.site.com will be going to the home page of site.com page by default.

It is in a lamp stack. Possible using htaccess? etc?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the settings for those ports in your httpd.conf file (located at apache/conf/httpd.conf), once you opened that up look for `listen 80` and change the `80` to your desired port.

note: do not forget to restart your webserver after these changes to update your config.

Comment: What should i do if it is a subdomain?

Comment: subdomain on a different port? and regular site on like lets say 80?

Comment: You would need to do that with VirtualHosts, read this http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/ for more info.